# Dynamic width console for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to run PowerShell as a variable width console and have the text wrap according to whatever the console width is at the time?

If it helps, I'm running the default PowerShell that comes with Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153983/are-there-any-better-command-prompts-for-windows/188086#188086) might help if you're manually resizing the window.

Comment: Now that Windows 10 is out, the correct answer is to upgrade to Windows 10. (And if necessary, turn off the legacy console, and enable line wrapping selection).